# Importing Camera Roll Image to UIView background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

A small warning: I'm a complete noob at swift

Im creating a small app that (will eventually) allow a user to draw over an image they choose from their camera roll on their iPhone. However, im having some trouble getting the image to be set as the background to the UIView (drawView). Could someone give me some pointers as to how I could go about this? The code I have scraped together is shown below.

My ViewController File:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,     UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var drawView : AnyObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    imagePicker.delegate = self

@IBAction func clearTapped() {
    var theDrawView: DrawView = drawView as! DrawView

    theDrawView.lines = []
    theDrawView.setNeedsDisplay()
}

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func importImage(sender: AnyObject) {


    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]){
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        drawView.backgroundImage = pickedImage

    }

    func dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


}


}
```

Also, my drawView has a separate swift file that deals with how the lines are drawn in it by the user.

Answer (score 0):

you're going to want to separate your code a little more. right now, it seems like you're trying to create a controller within a controller. implement a class that is a subclass of UIIMagePickerController with the necessary delegate (you already have the code, so just copy and paste):

```
class MyImagePicker: UIImagePickerController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

}
```

then in your view controller, initialize your image picker:

```
let myImagePicker = MyImagePicker()
```

call the correct method to return the image, set the background image of your UIView to that image, and then add that view as a subview:

```
drawView.backgroundImage = pickedImage
self.addSubview(pickedImage)
```

hope that works!